# Copy a google spreadsheet to another in a reverse order

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet contains thousands of rows.
sometimes i wanna check the newest data by my smart phone , 
(the newest data always on the bottom)
if i open the sheet it spent me vary long time to scroll it to the bottom to see the latest data.
So,is there anyway to copy the last 10 or 30 data to another sheet automatically , so i can save mytime ?

many thanks for helping my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i can tell you how to reverse the data we fetch. To reverse the order of the data we receive from the spreadsheet can be done using the following procedure.
What you need to do,, find following function, inside your functions file. like in my case in am using **GoogleSheet.php**

**`private function findRows($search=FALSE)`**

It should look like this:

**`private function findRows($search=FALSE)
{
   $query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_ListQuery();
   $query->setSpreadsheetKey($this->getSpreadsheetId());
   $query->setWorksheetId($this->getWorksheetId());`**

and add

**$query->setReverse('true');**

line after

**$query->setWorksheetId($this->getWorksheetId());**

This will reverse the order of data you will fetch.

i hope this will help you for reversing the data you receive.
thank you.